# How to use the package written by another language in AWS Lambda?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to import and use dataset package of python at AWS Lambda. The dataset package is about MySQL connection and executing queries. But, when I try to import it, there is an error.

"libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I think that the problem is because MySQL client package is necessary. But, there is no MySQL package in the machine of AWS Lambda.

How to add the third party program and how to link that?

Comment: You have to bring all the dependencies with you. So your package that you're importing should also include mysql package with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an os dependent system file. I'm guessing that you successfully installed the Python mysql client, but you still need the system mysql client, which seems to be a different version on your system than the lambda one. While building your virtual environment on the [official lambda image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) will definitely fix this problem, you *might* have some luck copying your own copy of this system file into your lambda zip file.

I found mine with

```
locate libmysqlclient.so.18
```

Note: depending on your system, the version number at the end might be different. Use the version in the error you receive.

Adding that file on the top level of my zip file with

```
cd \path\from\locate\to\libmysqlclient
```

followed by

```
zip -u \path\to\lambda\zip\file.zip libmysqlclient.so.18
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should install your packages in your lambda folder :

`$ pip install YOUR_MODULE -t YOUR_LAMBDA_FOLDER`

And then, compress your whole directory in a zip to upload in you lambda.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to include the binaries needed with your lambda package.

You need to utilize [pip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) and create an isolated environment.Your zip uploaded to lambda needs to have the python2.7/site-packages included (the ones installed with pip).

Now there are extreme cases of os-related dependencies. 
This has a tricky solution.
In those cases you have to spawn an amazon linux ec2 instance in order to build/get those dependencies and package them with your lambda.
Once your lambda is packaged you can close the ec2 instance.
Check [this](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html) guide if virtualenv is not enough.

Comment: This is one of those "extreme cases of os-related dependencies".